# TikZ: Specify the location of two 3D plots drawn in different axis environments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot two 3D functions using \addplot3. Both plots are defined within two separated axis environments (plotting them within the same axis produced worse results). I want to change the position where the plots are displayed. Currently, Plot 2 is displayed on top of Plot 1 (covering it). I want Plot 2 to be displayed above Plot 1. In the code below, I added an ellipse with the exact position I want each plot to be.

I tried using at={(x,y)} with the expected position as an option for the axis, but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Plot 1
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Expected Position
\draw (3.43,2.55)[very thick] ellipse (1.02in and 0.515in);
% Plot 1
\begin{axis}[axis equal, xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,zmin=0,zmax=1,hide axis]
\addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort,colormap={}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,128,0); rgb255(1cm)= (255,255,0);color(2cm)=(orange)}, samples=30,domain=0:1,y domain=0:2*pi]
({x * cos(deg(y))},
 {x* sin(deg(y))},
 {exp(-sqrt((x * cos(deg(y)))^2 + (x* sin(deg(y)))^2))}
);
\end{axis}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Plot 2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Expected Position
\draw (3.43,6.0)[very thick] ellipse (1.02in and 0.515in);
% Plot 2
\begin{axis}[axis equal, xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,zmin=2,zmax=3,hide axis]
\addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort, samples=30,domain=0:1,y domain=0:2*pi]
({x * cos(deg(y))},
 {x* sin(deg(y))},
 {-x^2+3}
 );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The current outcome is the following: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `grouplots` environment which, of course, groups plots. You can choose to display horizontally and vertically, with the distance you want.

If you want the `plot 2` to appear above, then you can list it first in the code. I left the command for the legend if you want, just uncomment it to use it.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[%
    group style={group size= 1 by 2, vertical sep=0cm,},
    height=5cm,width=6.4cm,
    %legend entries = {plot1,plot2}
    ]

% Plot 2
\nextgroupplot[axis equal, xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,zmin=2,zmax=3,hide axis]
\addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort, samples=30,domain=0:1,y domain=0:2*pi]
({x * cos(deg(y))},
 {x* sin(deg(y))},
 {-x^2+3}
 );

% Plot 1
\nextgroupplot[axis equal, xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,zmin=0,zmax=1,hide axis]
\addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort,colormap={}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,128,0); rgb255(1cm)= (255,255,0);color(2cm)=(orange)}, samples=30,domain=0:1,y domain=0:2*pi]
({x * cos(deg(y))},
 {x* sin(deg(y))},
 {exp(-sqrt((x * cos(deg(y)))^2 + (x* sin(deg(y)))^2))}
);
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way of controlling the space between the plots?

Comment: @totalUnimodular yes, the value `vertical space=0cm` can also be negative. That way it will be even smaller than my example.